# Import data from python dataframe to sql database

Tags: python, sql, dataframe

I need your help.

I have a list of information, which in form of list= [x0, x1,...x_end] ( with x0 = [name, phone number....]
=> about 25 details of one person)

I change the list into a dataframe, and now I want to push the data into SQL server database.

I use this line of code to insert a single data point to my database

```
cursor.execute('''
                INSERT INTO Table (name of all the columns)
                VALUES
                (all value of a certain row)
                ''')

conn.commit()
```

now I want to push all the rows from list or from dataframe to the database.

I try something like:

```
def insert_sql(x):
    cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO Table (name of all the columns)  VALUES(x)''') 
    conn.commit()
for i in list:
    insert_sql(i)
```

But it doesn't work.

Any idea?
Also, there are many columns. Is there any way to automatically insert the row without listing all the name of the columns like what I did above?

Answer (score 1):

Pandas provide a function to directly write your dataframe to DB, use the below function

`DataFrame.to_sql(name, con, schema=None, if_exists='fail', index=True, index_label=None, chunksize=None, dtype=None, method=None)`

First create a Table:

```
cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE Table_name (Brand text, Price number)')
conn.commit()
```

Next insert the records using to_sql:

```
your_df.to_sql('Table_name', conn, if_exists='replace', index = False)
```

Ref: [to_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)

Comment: will try that function. In case that the table is already there, do I need to name the columns in df precisely like the name in SQL table?

Comment: Yeah the column name in df and the sql table should match